# titlepage is not vertically centered

Tags: vertical-alignment, titles

I noticed that my titlepage is not vertically centered. I tried `\vfill`, `\vspace{\fill}`, `\vspace*`, and `\usepackage{titling}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}

         \usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

\begin{huge}
name of university \\
\end{huge}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Unilogo}
\end{figure}

\vspace{1cm}
{\Large name of institute} \\
\vspace{5mm}
Research focus \textit{research name} \\
Project \textit{project name} \\
\vspace{2cm}
\begin{large}
\textbf{title of thesis} \\
\end{large}
\vspace{5mm}
Master thesis in Biomedical Sciences \\
Submitted on Date \\
\vspace{1cm}
name \\
Matriculation number: \\
\vspace{2.5cm}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
{\bfseries Supervisors} & name and name\\
{\bfseries Examiners} & name and name \\
\end{tabular}

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` and see that it is almost centered. Are you aware that the (top/bottom) margins are not automatically symmetric?

Comment: Yes, but do they have to be? I thought \geometry{a4paper} does not need any modifications, does it?

Comment: I suggest that you have a look at the `geometry` documentation (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry). Try `\usepackage[showframe,margin=10mm]{geometry}` as a start so see the effect.

Comment: Just a side note: DON'T USE FLOATS!!! You want the image to be placed exactly where you put it in your code? Then get rid of the `figure`-environment and just use `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Please have a look at [title creation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation) and maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280/37907

Comment: Your example document produces `! Undefined control sequence.
l.21 \includegraphics`

Answer (score 1):

When you have markup such as

```
Submitted on Date \\
\vspace{1cm}
name
```

the vertical space is added after the line that contains `name` which is, I would guess, not what is intended.

Avoid all use of `\\` outside tables, and always put a blank line before `\vspace`

```
Submitted on Date

\vspace{1cm}
name
```

produces an output with the space between the two lines of text.

If you have a size change such as `\huge` always leave a blank line before the end of the group, or you will get huge text set on a normal size baseline.

Don't use `figure` inside a titlepage, just include the graphic.

You can vertically centre with `\vspace*{\fill}`

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}

\begin{huge}
name of university

\end{huge}


\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}


\vspace{1cm}
{\Large name of institute

}

\vspace{5mm}
Research focus \textit{research name} \\
Project \textit{project name}

\vspace{1.5cm}

\begin{large}
\textbf{title of thesis}

\end{large}

\vspace{5mm}
Master thesis in Biomedical Sciences \\
Submitted on Date 

\vspace{1cm}
name \\
Matriculation number:

\vspace{1.5cm}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
{\bfseries Supervisors} & name and name\\
{\bfseries Examiners} & name and name \\
\end{tabular}

\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```